# Connection to Parse from Australia is really slow

Tags: connection, parse-platform

We have created an application based on Parse. All our calls to Parse are working quite fast from Ukraine, but when other users in Australia use the application, it appears to be quite slow for them. We have run speed tests on their devices and their results are twice sometimes in three times slower than ours. They checked both being connected by 3g and Wi-Fi. The speed of the calls to Parse are very very slower. Could it be because Parse is in the US and our users are in Australia?

Comment: Same issues from Israel. Even when Parse's status is OK (i.e. no problems reported), many of my users seem to have problems connecting to Parse. I checked, and none of these users had slow Internet connections.